# Make div to continue to new line not jumping to new line

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs, I want to keep those side by side but if the text inside each div goes long, break the text to a new line and keep the next div beside that.

```html
<div style="float: left;">this is a text</div>
<div style="float: left; text-decoration: underline;">Will continue in next div</div>
<div style="float: left;">and this will be beside that</div>
```

I want to show above divs like this (the second div should have underline)

```
this is a text that will continue
in next div and this will be beside
that
```

Comment: I'm not getting the output you describe. As expected, the elements are next to each other horizontally, not vertically. Please clarify what your expected result looks like.

Comment: @connexo Sorry, I edited my question to make it clear. That is what I want to get.

Comment: Now your description above the code and the expectation you state under the code contradict each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a `div` element has a [`display`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) attribute value of `block` which will place it on its own line in the document. If you want them to be side-by-side, you can set the value to `inline` or [`inline-block`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) (if you want to set a width/height).

```css
div {
  font-size: 4rem;
  display: inline;
}

#second {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div>This text is in the first div element and</div>
<div id="second">continues into the second div element and</div>
<div>finishes in the third div element.</div>
```

---

If all you need the separate elements for is to underline the text in the second `div`, then I'd suggest you use a `span` instead to avoid the headache of removing styles from the `div`s and remembering to exclude them from any future CSS selectors.

```css
div {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.underline-me {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div>This text is all in one div element <span class="underline-me">even though this part is underlined</span> so it will flow without needing to change the display property</div>
```